# pwd: show mountpoint

Tags: mount, bind-mount

I have mounted a directory to another directory using `mount --bind` so that an sftp user of my server can access this directory.

```
mount --bind /path/share /path/home/user/stuff
```

I have put this in `/etc/fstab` and it is working great.

If I `cd` into the mounted directory and do `pwd`, it seems as if the directory is actually, physically there:

```
/path/home/user/stuff/share
```

Is there a command that shows where the 'original' directory is located
(just as symlinks: when you do `ls -fsl` you see the original path)?

Comment: I'm fairly sure no. A mount point isn't a symlink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `mount -l`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the directory is there, because you mounted it there. `mount --bind` tells the kernel to use an existing mount and attach it to another mount point. As far as the kernel is concerned,

```
mount /dev/something /path/share
mount --bind /path/share /path/home/user/stuff
```

and

```
mount /dev/something /path/home/user/stuff
mount --bind /path/share /path/home/user/stuff
```

are the same thing. There are two ways to distinguish them:

- If `/path/share` is not a mount point (i.e. it's part of a larger filesystem mounted at `/path` or `/`), you can tell the bind mount because it's not at the root of the filesystem.
- The `mount` program records its actions in `/etc/mtab`.

The `df` command reads `/etc/mtab`, so if a directory is on a filesystem that's been mounted with the `bind` option, you can see what the original path was with

```
df -P /path/to/file | awk 'NR==2 {print $1}'
```

(first field of the second line). Note that this information isn't always reliable, for example it's possible that the original filesystem has been unmounted and nothing, or something else, is now mounted at this location, as in

```
mount /dev/something /path/share
mount --bind /path/share /path/home/user/stuff
unmount /dev/something
mount /dev/somethingelse /path/share
```

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, you can now use `findmnt` (from `util-linux`) for that:

```
~$ sudo mount --bind /usr/local mnt
~$ cd mnt/bin
~/mnt/bin$ pwd
/home/stephane/mnt/bin
~/mnt/bin$ findmnt -T .
TARGET             SOURCE                             FSTYPE OPTIONS
/home/stephane/mnt /dev/mapper/VG-LV[/usr/local]      ext4   rw,noatime,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it actually finds it for you whereas `mount -l` just gives you a list of mounts and it's still up to you to figure out where it is.

Answer (score 1):

I checked source code of df, and made a similar script that will find the original path,

e.g you bind /tmp/a to /tmp/b,

And you launch my script with `perl script.pl /tmp/b/what/ever/deep/inside`, you will find `/tmp/a`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;

sub findmnt
{
    my $path = shift or die;

    open my $fh, 'mount|' or die;
    while (<$fh>)
    {
        return $1 if ($_ =~ qq{(.*) on $path type })
    }
};

if ($#ARGV lt 0)
{
    die 'Usage: ', $0, ' /path/to/dir', "\n";
}

my $mntpath = $ARGV[0];
while ($mntpath ne '/')
{
    my $origpath = findmnt $mntpath;
    if ($origpath ne '')
    {
        print 'Original path: ', $origpath, "\n";
        last;
    }

    $mntpath = dirname ($mntpath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on daisy's response, how about...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;

my $mntpath = $ARGV[0] or die "Missing required parameter <pathname>\n";
$mntpath = dirname ($mntpath) while (! grep / on $mntpath type /, `mount`);
```